# Should I create index on created_at column on database

Tags: database, postgresql, indexing

Maybe it is a dumb question but in my database schema i'm working on time based analyzing on simple posts table.
Is it a good idea to create index on created_at column on postgresql or database doing created_at index already?

In my post table

```
| post_id | user_id| some_post_stuff... | created_at |  
|:--------:|:--------------:|:--------:|:--------------:|  
| 1| 1 | hello #world | 05/05/2021 |  
| 2| 1| #stackoverflow is best | 05/05/2021 |
```

In my tags table

```
| tag_id | tag | trended_at |  
|:--------:|:--------------:|:--------:|  
| 1 | world | 05/05/2021 |  
| 2 | stackoverflow | 05/05/2021 |
```

In my post_tags table

```
| tag_id| post_id| created_at |  
|:--------:|:--------------:|:--------:|  
| 1| 1| 05/05/2021 |  
| 2| 2| 05/05/2021 |
```

I have wrote a function to find trend post with most popular tags. So every 15 minutes. Database cron jobs(nodejs client) function execute group by command on post_tags then found trends tag then selects posts. Should I create created_at index on post_tags.created_at because when I insert this table it updates primary key index file but created_at is important for this condition?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: [Edit] the question and include the `CREATE` statement of the table and the query or queries you want to support.

Comment: What type is `created_at` and `trended_at`?

Comment: Where are your SELECT, UPDATE and/or DELETE statements for this table? And the results from EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, VERBOSE) for these statements. Without knowing your queries and without knowing the query plans, we can only guess.

Comment: You can only decide whether to index or not if you know the queries and how often they are needed and how fast they have to be, and if you know how often table data are modified and how fast that has to be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Postgres does not create indexes for you (with the exception of primary keys). If you want to index something you need to add it yourself.

Should you index a column? Depends on how you're querying. Indexes are useful for both searching and ordering. Without indexes the database may have to search the whole table or spend a lot of time sorting the results.

You should index created_at if your queries have to search a lot of rows and order them with `order by created_at`, or use created_at in a where clause like `where created_at between '2015-01-01' and '2015-12-31 23:59:59'`.

If your queries return a small number of rows, you might not have to index created_at. For example: `select * from posts where user_id = X order by created_at` would probably use an index on user_id to filter the rows down to a small set. Sorting them by created_at will be quick, so no index is necessary.